# Failed to load : com/amazon/deequ/checks/Check

Tags: java, apache-spark, amazon-deequ

I'm building a spark application to load two json files, compare them, and print the differences. I also try to validate these files using amazon library `aws deequ` , but I'm getting the below exception:

```
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
20/08/07 11:56:33 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Error: Failed to load com.deeq.CompareDataFrames: com/amazon/deequ/checks/Check
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager).
log4j:WARN Please
```

when I submit the job to spark:

```
./spark-submit --class com.deeq.CompareDataFrames--master 
spark://saif-VirtualBox:7077 ~/Downloads/deeq-trial-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I'm using Ubuntu to host spark, it was working without any issues before I added deequ to run some validation. I wonder if I'm missing something in the deployment process. It doesn't seem like this error is a well-know one on the internet.

**Code :**

```java
import com.amazon.deequ.VerificationResult;
import com.amazon.deequ.VerificationSuite;
import com.amazon.deequ.checks.Check;
import com.amazon.deequ.checks.CheckLevel;
import com.amazon.deequ.checks.CheckStatus;
import com.amazon.deequ.constraints.Constraint;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;
import scala.Option;
import scala.Tuple2;
import scala.collection.mutable.ArraySeq;
import scala.collection.mutable.Seq;

public class CompareDataFrames {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder().appName("CompareDataFrames").getOrCreate();
        session.sparkContext().setLogLevel("ALL");

        StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[]{
                DataTypes.createStructField("CUST_ID", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("RECORD_LOCATOR_ID", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("EVNT_ID", DataTypes.StringType, true)
        });

        Dataset<Row> first = session.read().option("multiline", "true").schema(schema).json("/home/saif/Downloads/FILE_DEV1.json");
        System.out.println("======= DataSet 1 =======");
        first.printSchema();
        first.show(false);

        Dataset<Row> second = session.read().option("multiline", "true").schema(schema).json("/home/saif/Downloads/FILE_DEV2.json");
        System.out.println("======= DataSet 2 =======");
        second.printSchema();
        second.show(false);

        // This will show all the rows which are present in the first dataset
        // but not present in the second dataset. But the comparison is at row
        // level and not at column level.
        System.out.println("======= Expect =======");
        first.except(second).show();
        StructType one = first.schema();
        JavaPairRDD<String, Row> pair1 = first.toJavaRDD().mapToPair((PairFunction<Row, String, Row>)
                row -> new Tuple2<>(row.getString(1), row));
        JavaPairRDD<String, Row> pair2 = second.toJavaRDD().mapToPair((PairFunction<Row, String, Row>)
                row -> new Tuple2<>(row.getString(1), row));
        System.out.println("======= Pair1 & Pair2 were created =======");
        JavaPairRDD<String, Row> subs = pair1.subtractByKey(pair2);
        JavaRDD<Row> rdd = subs.values();
        Dataset<Row> diff = session.createDataFrame(rdd, one);
        System.out.println("======= Diff Show =======");
        diff.show();

        Seq<Constraint> cons = new ArraySeq<>(0);
        VerificationResult vr = new VerificationSuite().onData(first)
                .addCheck(new Check(CheckLevel.Error(), "unit test", cons)
                        .isComplete("EVNT_ID", Option.empty())
                )
                .run();
        Seq<Check> checkSeq = new ArraySeq<>(0);
        if (vr.status() != CheckStatus.Success()) {
            Dataset<Row> vrr = vr.checkResultsAsDataFrame(session, vr, checkSeq);
            vrr.show(false);
        }

    }

}
```

**Maven: **

```xml
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-catalyst_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazon.deequ</groupId>
            <artifactId>deequ</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-java8-compat_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the below approaches to resolve your problem.

**Approach 1.**

spark submit with `--jars` option,
Download the jar from the following Maven Repo to your machine, https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazon.deequ/deequ/1.0.4 to `~/Downloads/deequ-1.0.4.jar`

```
./spark-submit --class com.deeq.CompareDataFrames --master 
spark://saif-VirtualBox:7077 --jars ~/Downloads/deequ-1.0.4.jar ~/Downloads/deeq-trial-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

**Approach 2.**

spark submit with `--packages` option,

```
./spark-submit --class com.deeq.CompareDataFrames --master 
spark://saif-VirtualBox:7077 --packages com.amazon.deequ:deequ:1.0.4 ~/Downloads/deeq-trial-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

**Notes:**

1. The `--repositories` option is required only if some custom repository has to be referenced
   By default the maven central repository is used if the `--repositories` option is not provided
   When `--packages` option is specified, the submit operation tries to look for the packages and their dependencies in the `~/.ivy2/cache`, `~/.ivy2/jars`, `~/.m2/repository` directories.
   If they are not found, then they are downloaded from maven central using ivy and stored under the `~/.ivy2` directory.

**Edit 1:**

**Approach 3:**

If the above solutions 1 & 2 is not working then use `maven-shade-plugin` to build the `uber jar` and proceed with the `spark-submit`.
use the below `pom.xml` file for building uber jar using `maven-shade-plugin`. adding the below pom and rebuild your jar and deploy it with `spark-submit`.

```
spark-submit --class com.deeq.CompareDataFrames --master 
spark://saif-VirtualBox:7077 ~/Downloads/deeq-trial-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.deeq</groupId>
    <artifactId>deeq-trial-1.0-SNAPSHOT</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>Spark-3.0  Spark  Application</name>
    <url>https://maven.apache.org</url>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>codelds</id>
            <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <scala.version>2.12.8</scala.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <CodeCacheSize>512m</CodeCacheSize>
        <es.version>2.4.6</es.version>
    </properties>
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-catalyst_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazon.deequ</groupId>
            <artifactId>deequ</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-java8-compat_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>eclipse-add-source</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-test-compile-first</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-scaladocs</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>doc-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
                    <recompileMode>incremental</recompileMode>
                    <useZincServer>true</useZincServer>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-unchecked</arg>
                        <arg>-deprecation</arg>
                        <arg>-feature</arg>
                    </args>
                    <jvmArgs>
                        <jvmArg>-Xms1024m</jvmArg>
                        <jvmArg>-Xmx1024m</jvmArg>
                        <jvmArg>-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=${CodeCacheSize}</jvmArg>
                    </jvmArgs>
                    <javacArgs>
                        <javacArg>-source</javacArg>
                        <javacArg>${java.version}</javacArg>
                        <javacArg>-target</javacArg>
                        <javacArg>${java.version}</javacArg>
                        <javacArg>-Xlint:all,-serial,-path</javacArg>
                    </javacArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>org.xerial.snappy</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.scala-lang.modules</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.scala-lang</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </artifactSet>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <relocations>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>com.google.common</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>shaded.com.google.common</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                            </relocations>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I appreciate it. After trying the options you provided, I started getting different message `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class at com.amazon.deequ.checks.Check.<init>(Check.scala:61)  at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
 ... 14 more
20/08/07 15:34:47 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown`

Comment: Tried with option 2??

Comment: Yes, it gave me the same error. By the way , I'm using `Java 8`

Comment: Give me sometime let me build this project tomorrow and get back!

Comment: @SaifMasadeh : I built a uber jar and tested it in my local, please check the edit section in my answer. let me know if this helps!